# DB2 Selecting maximum row with group by

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables in a DB2 Database:

```
Products(Category, VendorId, Price)
Vendor(VendorId, Name)
```

I'm now trying to formulate the following query in SQL:

> For all categories select the Category, Price and Vendor Id and Vendor Name where
>   Price is the highest in the Category.

I can easily get the highest prices per Category by using

```
SELECT Category, max(Price) FROM Products GROUP BY Category
```

However I cannot add VendorId to the SELECT since that gives me an error -119, which, according to the manual, means

> A COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN A HAVING CLAUSE IS NOT VALID

But I'm not using a HAVING in my query. What would be the correct way to formulate my above query?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule say: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Grouping by category, there are multiple vendor-price pairs so it doesn't make sense to ask for "the" vendor of a category's group of rows. The straightforward solution is to first get category-price pairs where the price is the max price in the category then category-vendor-price triplets with such a category-price pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use row_number() for this, as follows:

```
select
   pv.Category, pv.Price, pv.VendorId,  pv.Name
from (
       select
          p.Category, p.Price, p.VendorId,  v.Name
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITON BY p.Category ORDER BY p.Price DESC) as rowno
       from Products p
       inner join Vendor v ON p.VendorId = v.VendorId
      ) pv
where pv.rowno = 1
```

This approach allows you to locate the whole row that contains the maximum price in each category. It is useful also for such things as "the latest order from each client"

Note, IF you have multiple products that would satisfy the "maximum price per category" criteria AND you want ALL those rows in the result then use RANK() or DENSE_RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: One could argue that thinking in terms of iterating over sets rather than sequences makes it unreasonably seem reasonable to entertain that the question is requesting or assuming exactly one vendor with max price per category.

Comment: I think you are saying *it is reasonable* to assume one (instance of) the maximum per set - and I have done that by using row_number(). Even so, if that assumption should be wrong, then multiple instances of a maximum per category can also be accommodated by the technique just substitute a different function.

Comment: You did make it clear about your assumption & possible substitutions in your answer. I said "it unreasonably makes it seem reasonable".to assume. I was suggesting that he straightforwad interpretation of the question suggests using RANK().